# console.log array TO Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, console.log

Dumb question. How to assign the array output that console.log currently displays to a JavaScript array on my index.js page.

**Example:**

```
var myjsarray = [ Whatever array is being displayed in console.log];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least not directly.

There is no API to access data displayed on the console.